# Reading data from USB Printer in C#

Tags: c#

I have a CUSTOM PLUS II USB printer that I need to send and receive status information.

I am able to send commands to the printer using the WritePrinter method using winspool but can't read the response. I can't find a single working example of the ReadPrinter method.

This is the main example I have used for writing data: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

I have tried to contact CUSTOM but get no response from them. Any other way to read from a USB printer would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Bidi Communication.  The SDK topic [starts here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/bidirectional-communication).  Beware for the rough ride, this is not friendly.  Especially not in C#, these are COM interfaces without a type library.

Comment: And 8 years later I go there and there is only a message saying "CONTENT REMOVED" /turns the table

Comment: For Pete's sake, click the link.  And propose an edit to correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

DataCard makes a c# wrapper for the IBidiSpl Interface, available in their [SDK](http://www.datacard.com/id/support_and_drivers/pre_license_agreement_sd_cd.jhtml?contentId=389869WkBgAQk&elementId=repositories/downloads/xml/XPS_SDF_4-0.xml&repositoryName=downloads), which I found in SD260 printer support.  The "Status" folder contains code to get bidirectional status data from a printer using the windows bidi API.